# On click listbox item navigate to page

Tags: c#, json, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a listbox with data binding.

```
<ListBox x:Name="EventsListBox" Margin="0,85,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="682" Width="480" HorizontalAlignment="Center" BorderThickness="0" Background="#FFE8E8E8" BorderBrush="#FF535353" SelectionChanged="EventsListBox_SelectionChanged">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Margin="5,5,5,0" Height="200" Width="470" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <Image Source="{Binding Default_Image, Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}" Margin="0" Stretch="Fill"  Width="480"/>
                <Image Source="gradient.png" Margin="0" Width="480"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="NameCont" Text="{Binding Title}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="10,0,0,10" FontSize="25" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I created new page like PageTemplate and I want to load data to that page based on user selected item. How can I make navigation? I'm using JSON.NET which load data to MainPage and generate ListBox items.

I want to make: when user click on item navigate to PageTemplate and load data to that page but how to make it with listbox?

Comment: One of the solutions might be to subscribe to `ListBox.SelectionChanged` event, and navigate when the event is invoked along with passing item ID to page.

Answer (score 0):

Just now I came across this solution and its very simple. It would be very simple in Listbox tap event. So add this line in your xaml in ListBox.

```
Tap="EventsListBox_Tap"
```

In listBox tap function, get the selectedIndex of the listbox and use that index in your listbox to get which list is tapped. Like the following code.

```
private void EventsListBox_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        YourClass Values = new YourClass();
        Values = yourList[EventsListBox.SelectedIndex];
    }
```

Now you get access to all your properties in **Values**, but these properties should be in your Class (**YourClass**). Use the value **Values** which holds the values you tapped and use it where ever you want. Like this,

```
    Values.Default_Image = Values.Default_Image;
    Values.Title = Values.Title;
```

Default_Image and Title properties should be in **YourClass**. That's it.